# Why does a slice expression of an empty slice have values in it?

Tags: go

Just started leaning Golang. Facing some trouble understanding the slice expression.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := make([]int, 0, 5)
    y := append(x, 20)
    fmt.Println(x, y, x[:2], y[:2])
}
```

Output:

```
[] [20] [20 0] [20 0]
```

Here's my understanding of what this represents:

- `x := make([]int, 0, 5)` - make a new slice of ints with 0 length and 5 capacity.
- `y := append(x, 20)` - create a a new slice using append function with length 1 & capacity of 5. `y` is `[20]`.
- `fmt.Println(x, y, x[:2], y[:2])`

  - How does `x[:2]` print `[20 0]`? Shouldn't it just cause an error? If this was the slice expression creating a new slice shouldn't it be `[0 0]`? How is the first value 20?

I am missing some fundamental concept here.

If I were to take a guess I think creating y using  `y := append(x, 20)` is somehow sharing the underlying memory. This is not shown when I print `x` directly, but when I am printing `x[:2]` it is shown.

Comment: Read the two official blog post about slices and append.

Comment: While learning slice, the explanation in [link](https://www.golangprograms.com/go-language/slices-in-golang-programming.html) was enough for me, I recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

> y := append(x, 20) - create a a new slice using append function with length 1 & capacity of 5. y is [20].

Not true. Because there is capacity already available, it does *not* allocate a new array. That is the whole point of pre-allocating a slice with capacity greater than its length.

```
x := make([]int, 0, 5)
```

Yields a slice [] over an array [0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

```
y := append(x, 20)
```

Yields a slice [20] over the same array, now [20, 0, 0, 0, 0].

```
fmt.Println(x, y, x[:2], y[:2])
```

Produces four slices:

```
x = [] // (its length & cap haven't changed)
y = [20] // (see append explanation above)
x[:2] = [20, 0] // (first two elements of the underlying array)
y[:2] = [20, 0] // (same two elements of the same array)
```

This is covered in detail in [the Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/8) and in further detail [on the Go blog](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro).

Comment: Can you please let me know why x prints `[]` while `x[:2]` print `[20 0]`?

Comment: Updated with further explanation.

Comment: Thank you. What I understood is that `x := make([]int, 0, 5)` creates an underlying array with capacity 5, all initialized to 0 and all the 4 slices describe different sections of this underlying array. Even though x has a length of 0 it is still possible to use `x[:2]` to refer to the fist two elements of the underlying array. Is this correct?